# Retrofit Rx android retry not working

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have following code

```
 public Retrofit provideRetorift(){

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

And api call as below

```
 apiService().getApiRespo()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .retry(5)
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(User user) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(User user) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

I have added okay http timeout as well as rx java retry still when i connect internet in between it will not retry.only works if internet available first time.

I am new to android can any one help me how to retry automatically when internet connect in between app trying to call api

Comment: If internet not available every retry will fail immediately. You will want to include some sort of delay between retries won't you?

Comment: @DaveMoten.thanks i searched many thread in google not found exactly how retry works.but your comment helped me .thanks for the clue for saying retry ill fail immediately

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post is usefull for you.

https://medium.com/@v.danylo/server-polling-and-retrying-failed-operations-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-8bcc7e641a5a

this code poll a server with backoff until receives a code different from 204. You should use retryWhen instead repeatWhen because you want to retry the request on error.

```
fun pollServerWithBackoff(videoId: String, maxAttempts: Int, delay: Int): Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> {
        return api.download(videoId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .repeatWhen {
                    it
                            .zipWith(Flowable.range(1, maxAttempts),
                                    BiFunction { _: Any?, attempt: Int -> attempt })
                            .flatMap {

                                Flowable.timer((it * delay).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            }

                }
                .takeUntil({

                    it.code() != 204
                })
                .filter {

                    it.code() != 204
                }
                .map{
                    if(it.code() in 200..300)
                        it
                    else
                        throw IOException(it.errorBody()?.toString() ?: "")
                }
    }
```